# product comparison across categories

Tags: java, machine-learning

I was looking a price comparison site like [this](http://www.junglee.com). So the question is how it knows two products from two different sites to be of same product and clubs the two to same bucket to show the price comparison.

If it is only books than i can understand that all books have unique `ISBN` number so just write some website specific code which will fetch data from the websites and  compare.

e.g. you have two websites:

```
www.xyz.com
www.pqr.com
```

Now these two websites list their books differently i.e. the html will be different, so parse the HTML and fetch `ISBN`, `price` from it. Than for corresponding `ISBN` we can put the two website's price. It is simple, but how you will parse for products which does not have an `id` which is **unique and uniform**  (like presser cooker, watch etc…) across websites like ISBN.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Other products also have identification numbers, in Europe it is the `EAN` which is currently turned into a global number called `GTIN`. In ecommerce usually Amazon IDs (`ASIN`, of which `ISBN` is a subset) are often used.

If you don't have these numbers available, which is usually the case, you will need a strategy called `Record Linkage` or `Data Matching`.

**TL;DR** It usually uses a string matching algorithm to find similar "worded" products (using an inverted index on n-grams for example). In the end you can use machine-learning to remove the wrong matches (false-positives). This requires a lot of training data (there are no or too small public datasets available) and thus most of the time a human will check those matches.

For a more detailed analysis of the problem I can only recommend reading the book [Data Matching by Peter Christen](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/3642311636). It goes deep into information retrieval (how to find similar products) and then how to sort out wrong or right matches using machine-learning (e.g. via structural analysis).

There are also plenty of papers by him available on the net, so checkout [his scholar profile](http://scholar.google.com/citations?user=oz-2CXsAAAAJ).